# Transforming complex object to table format (flat)

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
[
  {
    TEAMGROUP: "AB",
    TEAMNAME: "TEAM1",
    SPRINTS: [
      {
        ID: 1,
        NAME: "Name",
        STATE: "Open",
        GOAL: "Goal goes here",
        ESTIMATED: 5,
        COMPLETED: 3
      },
      {
        ID: 2,
        NAME: "Name",
        STATE: "In Progress",
        GOAL: "Goal goes here",
        ESTIMATED: 8,
        COMPLETED: 12
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    TEAMGROUP: "AB",
    TEAMNAME: "TEAM2",
    SPRINTS: [
      {
        ID: 4,
        NAME: "Name",
        STATE: "Closed",
        GOAL: "Goal goes here",
        ESTIMATED: 4,
        COMPLETED: 1
      },
      //...
    ]
  },
//...
]
```

And I would like it transformed into

```
[
  {
    TEAMGROUP: "AB",
    TEAMNAME: "TEAM1",
    ID: 1,
    NAME: "Name",
    STATE: "Open",
    GOAL: "Goal goes here",
    ESTIMATED: 5,
    COMPLETED: 3
  },
  {
    TEAMGROUP: "AB",
    TEAMNAME: "TEAM1",
    ID: 2,
    NAME: "Name",
    STATE: "In Progress",
    GOAL: "Goal goes here",
    ESTIMATED: 8,
    COMPLETED: 12
  },
  {
    TEAMGROUP: "AB",
    TEAMNAME: "TEAM2",
    ID: 4,
    NAME: "Name",
    STATE: "Closed",
    GOAL: "Goal goes here",
    ESTIMATED: 4,
    COMPLETED: 1
  },
  //...
]
```

I have tried various configurations of .map and .flatMap. But I cannot get the exact result I need.

I have tried:

```
    let teamData = this.filteredData.map( team =>
      team.sprints.map( sprint => sprint ) ).flat();
```

and other such variants.  This example returns the flattened arrays properly but does not also return the teamGroup or teamName.

I also tried something like:

```
    const teamData = this.filteredData.map( ( { teamName, teamGroup, months }, i ) => ( {
      teamName, teamGroup, months: months.flat()
    } ) );
```

but this does not flatten the months and returns everything.

Comment: What about mapping it yourself in the map function

Comment: @ukn Not a helpful comment. If I knew how to do that properly I would have. Do you have an example? Solution?

Comment: Thats not a "not helpful comment", thats kind of a question, I didnt know if you tried it but didnt like the code.

Comment: How can you go from one object to an array? What is the data that needs to be duplicated between the objetcs and what should be different. Is the json an object or you are missing bracket around the object?

Comment: @ukn I have edited the examples to be more accurate. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Well the answer is what i meant by mapping it yourself in the map function, that should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost got it; you just need to include TEAMNAME and TEAMGROUP in the object returned from your inner map:

```
let teamData = this.filteredData.map( team =>
  team.SPRINTS.map( sprint => ({
    TEAMNAME: team.TEAMNAME,
    TEAMGROUP: team.TEAMGROUP,
    ...sprint
  }) )
).flat();
```

And `this.filteredData.map(...).flat()` is equivalent to `this.filteredData.flatMap(...)`, so

```
let teamData = this.filteredData.flatMap( team =>
  team.SPRINTS.map( sprint => ({
    TEAMNAME: team.TEAMNAME,
    TEAMGROUP: team.TEAMGROUP,
    ...sprint
  }) )
);
```

Comment: BOOM!  That was it!  Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

First create a model for your JSON object:

```
class MyModel {
  TEAMGROUP: string;
  TEAMNAME: string;
  ID: number;
  NAME: string;
  STATE: string;
  GOAL: string;
  ESTIMATED: number;
  COMPLETED: number;
}
```

And then loop through your first level and second level array. With each loop create an object and push it to the new array:

```
const array = [{
  TEAMGROUP: 'AB',
  TEAMNAME: 'TEAM1',
  SPRINTS: [{
    ID: 1,
    NAME: 'Name',
    STATE: 'Open',
    GOAL: 'Goal goes here',
    ESTIMATED: 5,
    COMPLETED: 3
  },
    {
      ID: 2,
      NAME: 'Name',
      STATE: 'In Progress',
      GOAL: 'Goal goes here',
      ESTIMATED: 8,
      COMPLETED: 12
    }
  ]
}];

const newArray = [];
for (const item of array) {
  const newItem = new MyModel();
  newItem.TEAMNAME = item.TEAMNAME;
  newItem.TEAMGROUP = item.TEAMGROUP;

  for (const sprint of item.SPRINTS) {
    newItem.ID = sprint.ID,
      newItem.NAME = sprint.NAME,
      newItem.STATE = sprint.STATE,
      newItem.GOAL = sprint.GOAL,
      newItem.ESTIMATED = sprint.ESTIMATED,
      newItem.COMPLETED = sprint.COMPLETED;

        newArray.push(newItem);
  }
}
```

Comment: That won't work because SPRINTS is an array inside the main array (top level). I have edited my example to be more accurate/concise.

Comment: @h2hjastermereel revised based on your revised JSON object.

Comment: I knew I could do it that way but I was hoping for a slick way using map, flatmap, etc.

Comment: @h2hjastermereel I do not see an example for objects here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap I doubt if you can do that with a slick way.

Comment: Well you first extract the main array from the object. I do not need to put it back. So I am basically only working with the top array of values.